# How to run scheme in Julia?

Tags: julia, femtolisp

From the internet, I saw a discussion that run

```
julia --lisp
```

would start `femtolisp`.

I tried, the femtolisp quit as soon as it start:

```
PS C:\Users\Nick> julia --lisp
;  _
; |_ _ _ |_ _ |  . _ _
; | (-||||_(_)|__|_)|_)
;-------------------|----------------------------------------------------------

>
PS C:\Users\Nick>
```

I'm running Julia 0.3.8 on Windows 7. Anyone know what's wrong with this?

**Update**

I post a new issue here
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/11481

(Thanks, @IainDunning.)

Comment: This isn't an official feature of Julia, and I'm 99.9% sure its never been tested on Windows. Filing an issue on the Julia repository might provide some help, but I imagine that you'll need to figure it out yourself to get this one working.

Comment: You may want to use something like: `alias flisp='rlwrap julia --lisp'` in your shell configuration file, so you just need to call `flisp` with `readline` support enabled.